# mostrar un componente dentro de otro componente angular material

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material

Hola buenas tengo una duda... es que tengo 3 componentes y quisiera saber como haria para introducirlos a un mat-horizontal-stepper y que no sea simplemente copiando y pegando el codigo... quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de enviar toda la pantalla para mostrarla dentro del mat-stepper? muchas gracuas de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Eso lo haces con el selector del componente, por ejemplo si el selector es `my-app`:

`@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})`

Donde sea que quieras que aparezca ese componente solo lo insertas como una etiqueta `<my-app></my-app>`y ahí cargará ese componente.